# How does vnc client and vnc server negotiate port to talks

Tags: vnc

How does VNC client and VNC server negotiate port to talks?
Is it done using a well-known port?

Answer (score 3):

Default for direct connection: TCP 5900

Default for reverse VNC connection: TCP 5500

You can change the port it starts the connection by using the hostname:port format. If you want to change the listening ports you need to configure the server using the configuration tools.